# Frames Shown in Movie Editor>Mask Mode does not Match Frames Shown in Compositor

Tags: compositing-nodes, tracking, masking

I've been tracking some footage for a project, and wanted to mask out some of the tracking markers I placed in the area I filmed.
The first tracking marker worked fine in regard to masking, but for some reason, the second one I tried to mask is mismatched with what I see in the compositor.

On frame 67, for example, you can see that the mask is exactly over the tracking marker in the movie clip editor,
[image]

but in the compositor, on the same frame, the mask is in the right place, but the compositor is showing the wrong frame - this also happens when I render the frame.
[image]

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this?

Here are my compositor nodes:
[image]

Comment: You would have to probably share your file ... really hard to say for me. Try to disable Undistortion. Why are you using Scale for MovieClip? I would expect adjust Render Dimension to video size. Also you can use one Mask for several mask shapes parented to each track point individually (in case you want to fill mask by video with translation). If you plan to replace markers by still image  it is OK you have two of them, but than I don't thing you can Add them into a one mask like this to make a job.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, and I figured I'd put it on here in case anyone else is having the same problem.

After tracking, I was putting my movie clip through an undistortion node to remove lens distortion, which was changing the positions of objects near the edges, which was why the tracking marker near the edge was so off. I just put my markers through the undistort as well, and now it works perfectly.